# Git Refs error when running build in CI/CD pipeline (AWS CodeBuild)

Tags: git, github, aws-codebuild, lerna, monorepo

I have configured a CI/CD pipeline in AWS CodeBuild with a GitHub monorepo as source. When I merge a branch into master it triggers a build.

The build, configured in yaml file, has subsequent git commands and when I try to run `git fetch` I get ref head errors:

```
[Container] 2020/07/13 12:43:06 Running command git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /codebuild/output/id/src/github.com/***/repo/.git/

[Container] 2020/07/13 12:43:06 Running command git config user.email "user_email"

[Container] 2020/07/13 12:43:06 Running command git config user.name "***"

[Container] 2020/07/13 12:43:06 Running command git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/***/repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/***/repo.git (push)

[Container] 2020/07/13 12:43:06 Running command git remote set-url origin https://***:pwd@github.com/***/repo.git

[Container] 2020/07/13 12:43:06 Running command git fetch origin
error: refs/pull/1/head does not point to a valid object!
...
error: refs/pull/9/head does not point to a valid object!

[Container] 2020/07/13 12:43:07 Running command git checkout -f $GIT_BRANCH
error: refs/pull/1/head does not point to a valid object!
...
error: refs/pull/9/head does not point to a valid object!
Previous HEAD position was 46369d0 Update buildspec.yaml
Switched to branch 'master'

[Container] 2020/07/13 12:43:07 Running command git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I have tried `git reset` and `git rm -r --cached` but I can solve this issue.

When I was triggering the build after a push to the master branch, the build finished successfully. After having the repository updated in the container, I ran `lerna publish` to update the packages versions and deploy all the resources with Terraform.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? I have same issue.